# Passing argument of struct array when calling the function

Tags: c++

I want to know how to pass this argument when I call the function as the following:

```
void edit_book(struct library lib[] );
```

here I want to call the function with the arguments of the declared function:

```
edit_book();
```

I don't know the way to pass the arguments in c++

Comment: `edit_book(param);`, where `param` has the accordant type?

Comment: Should this even be a question for stack overflow?

Comment: You probably want to pass the size too.

Comment: I don't know the parameter that i should put in when call function

Answer (score 1):

Passing the argumentes in c++ is pretty easy, you only have to instance an array with your struct library and pass him in arguments.

```
struct library{
// Make your struct library here
};

int main() {
  library mylib[2];
  edit_book(mylib);
  return 0;
```

}